# Can I fly direct from Manila to Sydney? Sydney to Auckland? and exit in Sydney?

Tags: visas, australia, new-zealand

I am a Philipppine passport holder, I have visas for both countries Australia & New Zealand. Planning to travel for my birthday.
I want to fly directly from Manila to Sydney, spend 1 week in Sydney then fly to Auckland directly from Sydney and spend at least 1 week.
Then fly back again to Sydney and fly to Manila.
As long as I have the required visas for both countries I can enter without any problem with the immigration right?

Comment: You have the visas and airlines fly the routes. Do you have some reason to think there might be a problem?

Comment: Your edited question now asks if you'll have problems with immigration. We don't know. You say you have the required visas, so that's as much as you can do. Border guards have authority to deny you entry if they have reason to do so, regardless of your visa. Do _you_ know of a reason they might stop you?

Comment: You shouldn't have a problem, no. Make sure that you have a *multiple entry* visa for Australia, however.

Answer (score 3):

Well, yes.  There's Philippine Airlines and Cebu Pacific and others that fly direct from Manila to Sydney.

Then there are several airlines that fly to Auckland and back (Qantas, LATAM, Virgin, Air New Zealand, Jetstar and more).

So for the cheapest ticket, you'll perhaps want to consider booking a return ticket to Sydney, and a return ticket from Sydney to Auckland.